# Continuous function convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to answer the following problem, please help me:

Suppose that $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a jordan domain.

Consider an increasing sequence of continuous functions $f_n:\partial G\to \mathbb{R}, n\in\mathbb{N},$ that is uniformly bounded above.

let $u_n$, $ n\in\mathbb{N},$  be the solution of the Direchlet problem for $f_n$ in $G$.

Show that the corresponding sequence of functions $u_n$, $ n\in\mathbb{N},$ converges uniformly on $\bar G$ to a function $u$ harmonic in $G$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question says continuous functions $f_n$, but your title says holomorphic function convergence.  Which is it?

Comment: you are wright Mark. It is continuous.

Comment: I guess some conditions on $(f_n)$ are missing. An increasing sequence of continuous functions need not converge uniformly, even when they are uniformly bounded and defined on a compact set. If $u_n$ converges uniformly on $\bar{G}$, then the same must be true for $f_n = u_n|_{\partial G}$. So we have a contradiction when $(f_n)$ is chosen otherwise. On the other hand, if we know the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$ is also continuous, Dini's theorem improves this to uniform convergence and this can be used to prove the claim.

Comment: I edited the problem: $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ i dont know if that will change a thing. But we don't have more conditions of $f_n$. More over  $u_n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, is the solution of the Direchlet problem for $f_n$ in $G$ so $f_n = u_n|_{\partial G}$. Hence $f_n$ can not be chosen otherwise.

Comment: Notice that $u_n$ is determined by $f_n$. We have freedom to choose $(f_n)$ so long as it is continuous, increasing and uniformly bounded. So you can pick $(f_n)$ that does not converge uniformly. The result is that $u_n$ does not converge uniformly on $\bar{G}$, for otherwise $f_n = u_n|_G$ would have converged uniformly.

Comment: And if we suppose that More over $f_n$ converges uniformly .Can you please help me to prove the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Bbb{D}$ be the unit disc. By the [*Carathéodory's theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_theorem_(conformal_mapping)), there exists a homeomorphism $\varphi : \bar{\Bbb{D}} \to \bar{G}$ that is also a biholomorphic map $\Bbb{D} \to G$. Using $\varphi$, it suffices to prove the claim when $G = \Bbb{D}$ and we do so.

By the Poisson integral formula, each $u_n : \bar{\Bbb{D}} \to \Bbb{R}$ satisfies

$$ u_n (z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1-|z|^2}{|1 - e^{-it}z|^2} f_n ( e^{it}) \, dt, \qquad z \in \Bbb{D}. \tag{1} $$

Since $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is monotone increasing, $(u_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is also monotone increasing. Moreover, monotone convergence theorem applied to $\text{(1)}$ shows that $u_n$ converges pointwise to

$$ u(z) := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1-|z|^2}{|1 - e^{-it}z|^2} f ( e^{it}) \, dt $$

for each $z \in \Bbb{D}$.

Now let $f$ be the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$ and notice that $u$ thus defined solves the Dirichlet problem for the boundary data $f$ on $\Bbb{D}$. In particular, $u$ is harmonic on $\Bbb{D}$. Now for each compact subset $K$ of $\Bbb{D}$, the sequence $u_n$ increases to $u$ on $K$. Since both $(u_n)$ anbd $u$ are continuous on $K$, this convergence is uniform in view of the [*Dini's theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem). Therefore $(u_n)$ converges locally uniformly to the harmonic function $u$ as desired.

Comment: what will change in your proof if we consider the following problem:Suppose that $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a jordan domain. 

Consider an increasing sequence of continuous functions $f_n:\partial G\to \mathbb{R}, n\in\mathbb{N},$ that is uniformly bounded above. 

let $u_n$, $ n\in\mathbb{N},$  be the solution of the Direchlet problem for $f_n$ in $G$. 

Show that the corresponding sequence of functions $u_n$, $ n\in\mathbb{N},$ converges uniformly on $G$ to a function $u$ harmonic in $G$??

Comment: @aymen, You need only a minor adaptation in order to make my answer fit into your question. I can show you how to do this.

Comment: @aymen, Anyway, would you mind erasing your new answer? It is simply asking a corrected version of your original question, and in particular it seems not qualified as an answer. You can always edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

What will change in your proof if we consider the following problem:

Suppose that $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a jordan domain.

Consider an increasing sequence of continuous functions $f_n:\partial G\to \mathbb{R}, n\in\mathbb{N},$ that is uniformly bounded above.

let $u_n$, $ n\in\mathbb{N},$  be the solution of the Direchlet problem for $f_n$ in $G$.

Show that the corresponding sequence of functions $u_n$, $ n\in\mathbb{N},$ converges localy uniformly on $G$ to a function $u$ harmonic in $G$???

Thanks in advance.